# Django test data loading best-practices

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to understand best-practices around Django test data loading. I have a simple API that has some very long lists of returned JSON data, and I want to write a behaviorial test to make sure it works right.

Fixtures, or something like them, seem like they *should* do the trick - but it looks like Django fixtures are intended for seeding the database for tests, and not providing more general sampled/serialized data - e.g. I haven't been able to find an API that lets me load data from one specific fixture.

What's the generally-accepted way for me to manually store/version a file on disk that contains data that will be loaded and self.assertEqual'ed against in my test cases?

Any advice appreciated - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look at [factory_boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html) or [django model mommy](https://model-mommy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). They are  preferred way to load fixtures as compared to the default fixture loading supported by django. But if you really need to use django default fixture,

```
class SiteTests(TestCase):
    #This is the fixture:
    #-   fields: {content: lots of stuff, query: test, title:
    test, url: 'http://google.com'}
    #model: mine.site
    #pk: 1
    fixtures = ['mine']
```

where `mine` is the name of the fixture file. Take a look at http://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fixtures.html on how it is done.